# getAssets from Android Widget

Tags: android

The issue that I am having is I am trying to draw a custom font onto a widget(AppWidgetProvider). The issue now is that you cannot access ges tAssets() from and extension of AppWidgetProvider. Is there a way around this? Thanks!

*** UPDATE *** Here is what I have now after the feedback. The Widget doesn't display anything. what should my xml look like for this? Maybe that is where I'm going wrong now...

```
import java.text.DateFormat;
import java.util.Date;
import android.appwidget.AppWidgetProvider;
import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.Typeface;
import android.appwidget.AppWidgetManager;
import android.widget.RemoteViews;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.BitmapFactory;
import android.graphics.Canvas;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.graphics.Paint;
import android.graphics.Paint.Align;
import android.graphics.Typeface;
import android.widget.ImageView;

public class ClockWidgetXProvider extends AppWidgetProvider {

    public Bitmap buildUpdate(String string, Context context) {
        Bitmap myBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(160, 84, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_4444);
        Canvas myCanvas = new Canvas(myBitmap);
        Paint paint = new Paint();
        Typeface clock = Typeface.createFromAsset(context.getAssets(),"Carre.ttf");
        paint.setAntiAlias(true);
        paint.setSubpixelText(true);
        paint.setTypeface(clock);
        paint.setStyle(Paint.Style.FILL);
        paint.setColor(Color.WHITE);
        paint.setTextSize(65);
        paint.setTextAlign(Align.CENTER);
        myCanvas.drawText(string, 80, 60, paint);
        return myBitmap;
    }
    @Override
    public void onUpdate(Context context,
        AppWidgetManager appWidgetManager, int[] appWidgetIds) {
        RemoteViews view = new RemoteViews(context.getPackageName(), R.layout.clockwidget);
        String currentDateTimeString = DateFormat.getTimeInstance().format(new Date());
        view.setImageViewBitmap(R.id.time1, buildUpdate(currentDateTimeString, context));
        appWidgetManager.updateAppWidget(appWidgetIds, view);   
    }   
}
```

Comment: 1. Please post the error message you get. 2. Do you have the `Carre.ttf` in the `assets` directory?

Comment: The method getAssets() is undefined for the type ClockWidgetXProvider

Comment: Yes it is in the directory. The issue is that you cannot use getAssets  in AppWidgetProvider, it is restricted or not compatible. There must be a workaround.

Answer (score 1):

Change the method to

```
public Bitmap buildUpdate(String time, Context context) {
...
Typeface clock = Typeface.createFromAsset(context.getAssets(),"Carre.ttf");
```

Comment: The first letter in `context.getAssets()` is lowercase.

Comment: any idea's, i must be doing something wrong. no errors that Eclipse is throwing.